# Completely continuous map is not homotopy with antipodal map

Tags: algebraic-topology, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Define of completely continuous operator : $L$ is continuous operator and map bounded set to [relatively compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relatively_compact_subspace) set , then $L$ is completely continuous operator.

Now,  $E$ is a infinity dimensional Banach space, and $\Omega=\{x\in E : ||x||=1\}$ .

If $A:\Omega\rightarrow \Omega$ is completely continuous and 
$L:\Omega\rightarrow \Omega, L(x)=-x$, then how to show that $A$ is not homotopy with 
$L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Updated after modification of question)*

If $A$ is completely continuous then the closure of its range does not include all of $\Omega,$ since the unit sphere is closed but not compact. This establishes that the degree of $A$ is $0.$

Comment: So ,$degA=degL$?

Comment: Not necessarily. Perhaps you were looking for a homotopy inside a subset of $E$ rather than $E$ itself, but then you should also restrict the range of $A$ (e.g., require that it avoids the origin).

Comment: Yes, I should restrict the range of $A$. I have edited it. I think it is suitable question.

Comment: What is deg( antipodal map) ? +1 or -1 ?

Comment: Thanks ,but I still don't understand why degA is 0.Could you explain it in detail ? I just know the algebra define of degree of finite dimension and analysis define of degree of finite and infinite dimension.

Comment: Or give me some reference, thank you .

Comment: I do not know what the degree of such a map in general should be; I was using the term "degree 0" as a synonym of "homotopic to a constant" because your comment mentioned degrees. If you want to get an idea of the problem of defining degrees in infinite dimensions, have a look at this presentation: http://sugarcane.icmc.usp.br/PDFs/icmc-giugno2013-short.pdf You may want to pay special attention to the role of completely continuous maps, which is not exactly the same as in your current formulation of the question.