# Degree of infinite dimensinal antipodal map

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, banach-fixed-point

Let $E$ is a infinite dimensional Banach space and $\Omega=\{x\in E: ||x||=1\}$ .

$L:\Omega\rightarrow\Omega,L(x)=-x$, how to compute the degree of $L$?

In fact ,I just know that the algebra define of degree of finite dimension and analysis define of degree of finite and infinite dimension.

Besides, [why the degree of  completely continue map $A:\Omega\rightarrow\Omega$ is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678471/completely-continuous-map-is-not-homotopy-with-antipodal-map/1678476#1678476) ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by degree here. For at least many choices of $E$ (e.g. infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces) the unit ball of $E$ is contractible, so there's no algebro-topological notion of degree.

Comment: If I remember correctly, in fact, the unit sphere of any infinite-dimensional Banach space is contractible (and for separable infinite-dimensional Banach spaces, they are all homeomorphic to $\ell^2$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many classes of Banach spaces the unit sphere is diffeomorphic to the Banach space $E$. This is a result of Bassega. So we might as well talk about mappings from $E$ to $E$.

You have to specify which degree you mean here. A classical well defined notion of degree is the Leray-Schauder degree. This is a degree for mappings of the form
$$
f=I+K
$$
with $I$ the identity and $K$ a compact mapping. The LS degree is defined by the degrees of finite dimensional exhaustions. To go beyond this is much more difficult. You can look at a paper of Elworthy and Tromba. They add additional structures on the Banach space to obtain a $\mathbb{Z}$ valued degree.

The problem is that most (all?) Banach spaces have a contractible general linear group. This is a result due to Kuiper. That means that we can homotope $I$ to $-I$. On a separable Hilbert space it is not difficult to write such a path explicitly. So if one insists homotopy invariance these must have the same degree. The Leray-Schauder degree is only homotopy invariant under a restricted class of homotopies (of the same type as $f$ above), which is why we can do more with such mappings.

Another degree that is useful, but kind of weak, is the Smale degree. This is well defined for mappings $E\rightarrow E$ that are proper and Fredholm. Proper Fredholm mappings have an open and dense set of regular values (this is a theorem of Smale), and the preimage of a regular value is a proper Fredholm homotopy invariant. Unfortunately it cannot distinguish $I$ from $-I$ (as they are proper Fredholm homotopic). But it can for example distinguish the mapping $f:\mathbb{R}\oplus E\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \oplus E$ defined by $f(t,x)=(t^2,x)$ from the identity.